# Customize camera view toolbar in Titanium SDk

Tags: iphone, camera, titanium, toolbar

Is there any way so that we can customize toolbar that is bottom of camera view in Titanium SDK. Can we add custom control on this? Any code or idea will appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the overlay property of the camera and then you can specify your own buttons. There is an example in the kitchen sink